# Strange issue with Blogspots widgets CSS position: fixed; and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, widget, blogger, css-position

I've added a new widget to my blog http://kasperikoski.blogspot.fi, which basically works as a menu by using "Add HTML/Script". The code is to bloggers HTML/CSS:

```
.menukadn   {
line-height: 1;
}

a.limeka, a.limeka:visited, a.limeka:active {
font-family: 'Maven Pro', sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #bbb;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
transition: color 150ms linear;
letter-spacing: -0.090em;
```

}

```
a.limeka:hover  {
color: #21a97e;
transition: color 150ms linear;
```

}

And to the WIDGET:

```
<div class="menukadn">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/Kadnnn" class="limeka" title="" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
<br/>
<a href="http://instagram.com/kasperikoski" class="limeka" title="" target="_blank">Instagram</a>
</div>
```

When I try to add positioning like this,

```
.menukadn   {
line-height: 1;
position: fixed;
}
```

or alternativly to the widget DIV#HTML1 to itself:

```
#HTML1 {
position: fixed;
}
```

it works perfectly at Mozilla Firefox but in Chrome my widget #HTML1 is located approximatly 800px right from where it should be (column-left-outer), just next to inner bodys left border. Any ideas that could there be some other code causing contradiction?

Comment: I wanted to tackle your problem but I do not see that widget on your site.

Comment: user850010 try to use Google chrome. It is there but it is somewhere 500-800 px left of your screen. If you are willing to offer me your help, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

For **#HTML1** remove `margin-left: -672px;` and add `left:0px`

For **.menukadn** add `margin-left: 250px`

Comment: I tried, but now it behaves just like "absolute". ny other ideas? I also could attatch the whole XML somewhere here...

Here is my XML blog template 7zipped

[http://www.kolumbus.fi/kadn/blogtemplate.7z]

Comment: Try this:

For #HTML1 remove margin-left: -672px; and add left:0px

For .menukadn add margin-left: 250px


That didn't work either. Please see the results now.

Comment: Please feel free to copy the whole template to your own blog for test purposes.

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding on what you want to achieve:) I now have on both Firefox and Chrome widget on the left side of the content and it is fixed positioned. Also thanks for the template.

Comment: Screenshot from firefox browser https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/--bGKg3F7FyQ/UXPorc6RmhI/AAAAAAAAA8o/25P4HoQ1_pE/w1007-h428-p-o/example.jpg - I assumed this is what you wanted:)

Comment: Yeh I know, but still its horizontal position in blogs body between left and right border is relative to your browser windows width.

What I mean is that is there possible to position it left not from pages left side but from left border so, that it still would been fixed. See what I've done now. Works like a charm in Firefox, but not in Chrome and i dont know why :(

Comment: I'm not that good at CSS, so I'm unable to fix the issue. Maybe you could repost your question and instead of emphasis on blogger this time just mention in your title "position:fixed not working in chrome" or something similar. With this title you will probably get more interest from CSS experts here.